# How can I improve this question I have at hand?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality-improvement

So I have [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72994263/are-glvalues-really-just-prvalue-with-a-memory-adress-and-can-they-be-differenti/) which I have tried to improve so many times, that it feels like I am holding a monologue at this point.
I also mentioned this question [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419348/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-are-downvoted-because-of-disagreement?noredirect=1).

But everything I ever got, apart from the tip that I shouldn't indicate the numerous edits I made, was just links to sites like https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/, [http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/faqs/smart-questions.html) and sites similar to those.

I have already done everything that is mentioned in those sites so linking me another one really won't help.

What I need is concrete tips on how to improve this question.

Comment: As a side note, some of those downvotes will likely be due to the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) from your prior (deleted) question. Though I hope users (hopefully SMEs in C++) will be able to give you pointers, recovering the question to a positive score may be difficult without those who downvoted changing their votes.

Comment: There are some spelling mistakes that can be fixed, and some other cosmetic edits can be made. Other than that, I don't really see much that can be improved about it. It's also a better question than the average C++ question, so I don't know why it was so negatively received. I mean the negative reception prior to your previous meta post. The negative reception after that is just how meta usually works (see Larnu's link for details.)

Comment: Ok I fixed all spelling mistakes I found.

Comment: Side note: digging into differences between some deep details of language specs is an area favored by trolls... it is very easy to write good looking question for those... but very hard to make it "practical programming question".  I'm not c/c++ language-lawyer, so I can't say whether links you presented in the post are authoritative, but links from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues look better... I personally would not vouch that you *are not trolling* (posting to just trigger pointless discussions).

Comment: Related deleted meta post (10k+ only) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419348/how-to-deal-with-questions-that-are-downvoted-because-of-disagreement

Comment: It might be worth noting that the question has changed substantially since its first revision, and some of the downvotes may still reflect the quality of the question in that previous state, as we cannot expect all voters to get back to the question.

Comment: A few Remarks: Asking a Qt (Question) on 'Main' or 'Meta' and then deleting it is never really well perceived, as it implies some "wasted time" for any Commenters/Answerers while being active in the c/c++ Tags with many Advanced Users with 10k+ Rep who can still see those deleted Qt's... // Apart from 2 Comments in the first 15 min, you didn't "really" follow up, with no Follow-up at all (unless it got deleted...?) on the 3 Answers that Qt received (except maybe 1 Upvote on one...?)... // From the 8 (visible) Qt's, 5 got also closed as 'Duplicate' and sound very "basic" to me...

Answer (score 10):

Take my answer with a grain of salt, because I don't know C++, but from what I can see after a brief google is that your question is based on a false premise, and does not have much convincing information to back it up. But worse, it *says* that it actually *does* have lots of information to back it up:

For example, you state:

> There are countless explanations as to what the differences between glvalues and prvalues are

But don't share any of those countless explanations. In a case like this, sharing something from a reputable source like cppreference.com, docs.microsoft.com, even Wikipedia, or something similar should really be included to back up your statement, because if your definition is wrong, then that's the first place people will point you to go find the answer... and it's the first place you really should have looked.

If an asker can't bother to show they looked at the authoritative reference when asking such a question, then it's likely that the question will accrue downvotes for lack of research effort.

Likewise, you reference some random YouTube video/person as having the same opinion as you, as if that is convincing evidence that you are correct. Who is this YouTuber? Are they a well-known C++ programmer/evangelist? There's a big difference between a video by Bjarne Stroustrup vs a video by someone named 10xleetprogramer2022 (for example).

The grammar issues and changing of the question title to ask an additional question halfway through the process also aren't doing you any favors.

Comment: I arrived to the same conclusion as you, which makes me think you are right. oh, wait...

Comment: Can't wait to see the "Stack Overflow is toxic" YouTube video from 10xleetprogramer2022.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But how should I now change the question to make it better?

Comment: @tempdevnova Well, I would infer from this answer that the issues I raised here are what need to be addressed. Unfortunately the first issue (basing the question on a false premise) is not something you can really "fix" without deleting the question and asking a new one, and that's out because you've already received answers. The second issue is that you did not cite any authoritative sources. You've fixed that already by citing cppreference.com.

Comment: @tempdevnova The third issue can be resolved by either removing the claim that the random YouTube user had the same understanding as you *or* by explaining in specific detail what the YouTuber said and how you think that matches up with your understanding (I'd recommend the former).

Comment: @tempdevnova The final issue is not something you can "fix", per se, except by not doing it any further: once you've asked a question and received some attention on the post via an answer, you should only make clarifying edits to the question body and title. Changing the post so that it asks _additional things_ or even _different things altogether_ is bad and frustrates those trying to help.

Comment: All that being said, you've already gotten some good responses on the question, and all things considered you have come out *ahead*, account/rep-wise. Yes, the question is still negatively-scored at -3, but for the 24 reputation you've lost, you've *gained* 90 reputation from upvotes. And now that I look at it today, I see you've already updated the question to remove the reference to the YouTuber and cite a book (I'm assuming that is a book), instead, which is probably better in the eyes of the C++ community (they seem to prefer learning from books :-P).

Answer (score 2):

I gave it an upvote because I believe I found a fragment that was worth answering (where by 'worth' I mean a chance it can help future visitors in clarifying their conceptual misunderstanding), but the shortcomings are notable:

- The first sentence contains a false premise. I think that is fine and addressing it is useful to future StackOverflow visitors who may have similar thoughts. Both comments and answers focused on that.
- The second sentence is a supposed conclusion that contradicts the premise it claims to come from (premise: prvalue has no address by definition, conclusion mentions a "prvalue with an address"). Then we have the 1st question "Is that correct?".

Then came the edits that were not actual *edits* but *add-ons* that made it lose focus (and currently there's 1 vote to close for that reason, that I agree with):

- edit to respond to the comments saying you've read the definition and still think your question stands.
- edit to acknowledge that "the answer to my original question is no.", followed by a *new* question
- edit bringing back the first question and a link to a Youtube video which is spectacularly incorrect, in a lot more ways than your initial premise.